# How to allign my RSS feed to the right of my google map

Tags: html, css, rss

I'm trying to implement a RSS feed and move it to the right of my Google Maps API, but it stay in the bottom of the page.
Can someone help me?

Here is an image of my page:
[image]

Here is the code of the rss feed:

```
<div id="widgetmain" style="text-align:left;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;width:200px;background-color:#transparent; border:1px solid #333333;">
    <div id="rsswidget" style="height:500px;">
        <iframe src="http://us1.rssfeedwidget.com/getrss.php?time=1495402870570&amp;x=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Fthr%2Freviews%2Fallreviews&amp;w=200&amp;h=500&amp;bc=333333&amp;bw=1&amp;bgc=transparent&amp;m=10&amp;it=true&amp;t=(default)&amp;tc=333333&amp;ts=15&amp;tb=transparent&amp;il=true&amp;lc=000003&amp;ls=14&amp;lb=true&amp;id=false&amp;dc=333333&amp;ds=14&amp;idt=true&amp;dtc=000000&amp;dts=12" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0; width:200px; height:500px;" id="rssOutput">Reading RSS Feed ...
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0;border-top:1px solid #333333;" id="widgetbottom">
        <span style="font-size:70%"><a href="http://www.rssfeedwidget.com">RSS feed</a>&nbsp;</span>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using float. Under the "style" of the first div, put "float: right"

Comment: did'nt worked. It just moved the RSS Feed to the right, but still on the bottom

Comment: Put display:inline-block; under the style of the map

Comment: The combination of the "float:right" inside the div, and the "display:inline-block;" in the css of the map, worked for me. Thanks!